# Problem installing SKS on Debian 12

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I need to install SKS on Debian 12, but got such problem:

```shellsession
root@SRV1:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@SRV1:~# apt install sks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
sks is already the newest version (1.1.6+git20210302.c3ba6d5a-4+b2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sks : Depends: db-util but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: db5.3-util but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried

```shell
apt --fix-broken install
```

but it didn't help. I'm running newest Debian 12 image on VirtualBox.

Comment: `I'm running newest Debian 12 image on VirtualBox.` are you sure about that? Debian 12 is Bookworm, not Bullseye as your output shows

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, sources list is wrong, I will change it to bookworm and see if it will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I must made a mistake with sources.list.
I got such content there:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

I've changed it to:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

And now it's working as expected.